# NLog + SQLite + Wpf (asp net core) - лог не пишется в бд

Tags: wpf, sqlite, asp.net-core, nlog

1. Есть проект WPF на ASP NET Core 3.1
2. Через NuGet подключил пакет NLog
3. Добавил в проект файл NLog.config
4. В базе данных SQLite создал таблицу Logs
5. Содержание NLog.config

```
<targets>
    <target name="database" xsi:type="Database"
            keepConnection="false"
            useTransactions="false"
            dbProvider="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection, Microsoft.Data.Sqlite"
              connectionString="DataSource=TestDb.db;"
            commandText="Layout" >
        <commandText>
        insert into Logs(Timestamp, Loglevel, Callsite, Message) values(@Timestamp, @Loglevel, @Callsite, @Message);
     </commandText>
        <parameter name="@Timestamp" layout="${longdate}"/>
        <parameter name="@Loglevel" layout="${level:uppercase=true}"/>
        <parameter name="@Callsite" layout="${callsite:filename=true}"/>
        <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}"/>
    </target>
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database" />
</rules>
```

6. Базу данных, соответственно, положил в Debug папку
7. На бэкенде пробую писать что-то в лог

```
try
{
    ILogger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    logger.Info("First log in this application");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
            
    throw;
}
```

7. Отрабатывает без эксепшена, но в базу данных ничего не пишет.

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Как WPF может быть на ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Путём,  некоторых манипуляций может. Но суть не в том, что проект на WPF.

Comment: Ну я вижу информацию про это тут, вижу метки и спрашиваю, как? ASP - это WEB технология, на ней пишут сайты, не более.

Comment: По поводу проблемы, а вы пакет то подключили самого SQLite?

Comment: Да, пакет подключен, база данных работает.

Comment: [он](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SQLite/)?

Comment: Да - Microsoft.Data.SQLite - это он.

Comment: Предположу, что есть две (или более) баз с именем TestDb.db, расположенных в разных папках. Логи пишутся в одну, а вы смотрите в другой.